# URL downloaded from CloudKit crashes app during button push

Tags: swift, url, crash, openurl

I have the Facebook URL downloaded from CloudKit, contained in my facebookurl variable. url is set up to take the string from facebookurl and turn it into a viable URL for the open function in the last line. However, every attempt at opening this button in my running app crashes, leaving me with this generic error: 
[Error message in debug area and in code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPXrM.png)

```
   let facebookurl = detail.value(forKey: "Facebook") as? String
    let url = URL(string: "\(facebookurl)")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that a valid URL it's returning? Try setting a break-point, and then print out whatever is being returned as facebookurl - then copy and paste it in your browser. Also you'd be wise to use optional binding for your URL - not just force-unwrapping a potentially nil value.

Comment: Unfortunately, the URL is valid. Would you be able to suggest how to optionally bind my URL? I'm unfamiliar with this resolution.

Comment: Just basically add an if statement in front of what you've already done, but with brackets at the end `if let facebookurl = detail.value(ForKey: "Facebook") as! String? { ...(process facebookurl) }`

Comment: The problem it is probably in your string interpolation probably returning "optional(whatever)". unwrap the value using if let and unwrap your url. Don't force it

Comment: `if let facebook = detail.value(forKey: "Facebook") as? String, let url = URL(string: facebook) { UIApplication.shared.open(url) }`

Comment: Note: when working with Swift 3 it is recommended to work with its native dictionary type `[AnyHashable:Any]` instead of NSDictionary.

Comment: syntax would be `if let facebook = detail["Facebook"] as? String,
    let url = URL(string: facebook) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}`

Comment: Appreciate the help Pierce and Leo Dabus!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pierce and Leo Dabus,

I altered my code like such -

```
if let facebookurl = detail.value(ForKey: "Facebook") as! String?
{
  let url = URL(string: facebookurl)
  UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```